# How to specify ELF section alignment in GNU as?

Tags: assembly, elf, memory-alignment, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to use GNU `as` as a generic assembler similar in use as `nasm`. I make a template source like this:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
.intel_syntax noprefix
_start:
call 0xb77431c0 # the instruction I want to assemble
```

And then I run the assemble command like this:

```
as --32 -o test.o test.s
ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0xb77431d9 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

All works well with binutils 2.24. But it appears that `as` from binutils 2.22 (the one in Ubuntu Precise) aligns `.text` section to the 4-byte boundary, thus instead of the expected disassembly I get wrong results:

```
 # expected and working in binutils 2.24
$ ndisasm -b 32 -o 0xb77431d9 test.bin
B77431D9  E8E2FFFFFF        call dword 0xb77431c0

 # actual in binutils 2.22
$ ndisasm -b 32 -o 0xb77431d9 test.bin
B77431D9  90                nop
B77431DA  90                nop
B77431DB  90                nop
B77431DC  E8DFFFFFFF        call dword 0xb77431c0
```

The problem is in the `as` command (i.e. not `ld`): `readelf -S` gives me the following for results of `as` 2.22:

```
$ readelf -S test.o | grep ' \.text'
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000005 00  AX  0   0  4
```

And for 2.24 I have

```
$ readelf -S test.o | grep ' \.text'
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000005 00  AX  0   0  1
```

So the problem is indeed alignment of `.text` section. I've tried placing `.align 0` and `.align 1` in various places in the source, but it didn't change the output.

So my **question** now: how to explicitly specify section alignment for ELF target in GNU assembler?

Comment: I really wish this were possible inside assembly directly, without a linker script. It's very sad :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the default linker script *LD* is causing some kind of forced alignment. I'd create a basic linker script with the origin point, and tell it which sections you want (specifying the alignment), and in what order sections will appear.

**linker.ld**

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xb77431d9;
    .text . : SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

This script utilizes the [*SUBALIGN*](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Linker.pdf) directive to override the alignment of the `.text` section as it appears in the input object. From the GNU Linker documentation it has this effect:

> 3.6.8.4 Forced Input Alignment
>
> > You can force input section alignment within an output section by using SUBALIGN. The
> >     value specified overrides any alignment given by input sections, whether larger or smaller.

Then use:

```
as --32 -o test.o test.s
ld -T linker.ld -m elf_i386 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
```

The output I get here is:

```
ndisasm -b 32 -o 0xb77431d9 test.bin
B77431D9  E8E2FFFFFF        call dword 0xb77431c0
```

---

When a section in an object file(s) doesn't get processed by the sections in the linker script, the input sections will still be emitted. All unprocessed input sections will be output at the end in the order they were encountered by the linker.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The call target changes this way: it should be `0xb77431c0`, but appears instead to be `0xb77431bd`.

Comment: Your answer actually does help, although doesn't fully solve the problem. I've made a bit of improvement, and posted the working solution.

Comment: Oh I forgot what you originally encoded in the original nasm.

Comment: @Ruslan : Ah I was working on a new answer, and didn't see you posted a similar fix. I've also upvoted your answer since it seems rather close to this. Sorry about that. That was what I get for doing this at 3am.

Comment: No problem. I think I'll accept yours, since it has a bit more details — so that future visitors are exposed to them immediately.