# Optimization for size through removing garbage characters from strings iin C++

Tags: c++, optimization

I have two versions of a Hello World program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout<<"Hello World and a very long message";
}
```

I would expect a different size of resulting binaries for these, if a rigorous size optimization is performed. However, when I compile with `g++ -Os -o test test.cpp -Wl,--strip-all` (with `GCC 5.4.0`), I am getting equal file sizes (6336 on my system, which is `Ubuntu`). This implies that there is some garbage space for a buffer of some minimal size (although in this example I expect strings to be `const char[]`).

My question: what is the nature of this buffer and how to remove garbage characters from the produced binary?

Comment: Probably be a good idea to specify your target system.    Different systems have different executable formats, and different alignments or minimum sizes of various parts of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aligning takes place here.

The linker aligns things to page size (4K) by default. See below for reference:

[How to specify ELF section alignment in GNU as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956010/how-to-specify-elf-section-alignment-in-gnu-as)

[How to change alignment of code segment in ELF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005638/how-to-change-alignment-of-code-segment-in-elf)

There's also code alignment (instruction alignment) which affects performance greatly, but this is not related to string literals so I will omit here.

Comment: The difference becomes noticeable if I compile, e.g., with `-Wl,-z,max-page-size=32`.