# How to get relative offset of function in C

Tags: c, amiga

Is there a way to get the compiler to set constants to relative offsets of symbols further down?

I am using GCC but vbcc or SAS/C is also options.

I am porting a bit of Assembly code to C and in it the first thing in the .text section is relative offsets to various symbols further down. So my code starts with

```
static const ULONG offTokenTable=&tokenTable;
static const ULONG offFirstFunction=&myfunc;

....

static const UWORD tokenTable[]=(const UWORD[]){ ...... };

....

void myFunc() {
   ....
}
```

I want offTokenTable to be something like 0x10 (given that tokenTable is 0x10 bytes from start of offTokenTable. The assembler seems to easily figure this out by something like

```
Start dc.l tokenTable-Start
      dc.l myFunc-Start
....
tokenTable
      ....
....
myFunc
....
rts
```

Comment: Do you need those fixed to a specific constant for some reason?  I'd expect the code you had in your first block assigns values appropriately.

Comment: They need to come first. AMOS Basic expects its extensions to begin with offsets to token tables, title, length etc. The whole thing is coded in assembler and makes assumptions that mostly makes sense in assembly. I am trying to write an extension in C. The pointers are written as 0x00000000 in the object file. I'm guessing that the compiler does not know the offsets during compile time and maybe the header needs to be generated afterwards and linked in somehow.

Comment: The C standard does not provide a way to calculate such offsets during compilation.

Comment: I see.  I might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956010/how-to-specify-elf-section-alignment-in-gnu-as and see what they're doing with the linker

Comment: Compilers often provide a way for you to compile as "position independent code". But it rather sounds as if you need a way to allocated variables at fixed addresses, which can be done through linker scripts and compiler extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to get offsets of symbols into the header of the file is to do it in multiple steps. First you build your main file with all the things you want offsets to. And then you list the symbols with

```
nm -n mainfile.o
```

Parse it and generate a header file with the offsets from that like

```
static const ULONG offTknTable = 0x8;
static const ULONG offTitle = 0xc;
static const ULONG offFirstFunc = 0x20;
```

Compile and link it

```
gcc -c header.c
ln -o extension.lib header.c main.c
```

The default linker script seems to be ok at first glance. If not I might have to write a custom linker script do get everything in right place.

I found a great page describing linker scripts: https://mcyoung.xyz/2021/06/01/linker-script/